# How to execute @Before from Aspect depending on passed parameter to method

Tags: java, spring, aspect

I have had an implemented aspect which checks whether a user is a premium user and depending on that I could throw a matching exception. I would check with a custom annotation on a method. I would fetch the user from the securityContext and do like so:

```
@Before(value = "@annotation(com.selfcast.annotation.RequiresBasic)")
public void requirePremiumForAction() {
    var talent = Optional.of((JwtAuthentication) SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
            .getAuthentication())
            .map(authUtil::getCredentials)
            .map(x -> userService.whoAmTalent(x.getEmail()))
            .orElseThrow(NoSuchTalent::new);

        if (
                paymentLaunchService.hasPaymentLaunchedInCountry(talent.getCountry().getId()) &&
                !talent.getAccountKind().equals(AccountKind.BASIC) &&
                !talent.getAccountKind().equals(AccountKind.FREEMIUM)
        ) {
            throw new ActionRequiresPremium();
        }
}
```

How do I proceed when I want to execute this depending on a parameter a method receives? I would need to fetch an object based on its ID, check a property of that object and only then return an ActionRequiresPremium exception. Like so:

```
@RequiresBasic
public Object doSomething(String Id){
  
}
```

Is this even possible? As far as I could research it is not. However using something like an @After seems pointless. What are good alternatives if this isn't possible?

Comment: You can use the `JoinPoint` as an argumetn and on that you can call `getArgs`.

Comment: @M.Deinum I thought that theres no way I can access those parameters before the method is executed. You are right though, it works. Thank you! Please post your answer as a reply so I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`JoinPoint`](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/runtime-api/org/aspectj/lang/JoinPoint.html) as an argument in your advice. When you have that you can use the [`getArgs`](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/runtime-api/org/aspectj/lang/JoinPoint.html#getArgs()) method to obtain the arguments of the method being called.

```java
@Before(value = "@annotation(com.selfcast.annotation.RequiresBasic)")
public void requirePremiumForAction(JoinPoint jp) {
    var args = jp.getArgs(); // Now do your thing with the arguments as needed
    ... Remainder ommitted
}
```